# How to call method from library in VolleyController in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am using [this](https://github.com/cnzx219/android-uninstall-feedback) library to show a feedback web survey if the user uninstalls my app. Its common for software to get your feedback after uninstalling their software so I would like to implement the same to get user feedback as to why they are uninstalling. Now that I've explained why I'm choosing to use this, here's what I've tried.

My VolleyController extends Application. It has this for the onCreate() method:

```
 private static VolleyController instance;

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    UninstallFB.init(this, "http://www.google.com");
    instance = this;
}
```

According to the librarys' ReadMe, you're supposed to add the line `UninstallFB.init(this, "http://www.google.com");` within the applications' onCreate method. When doing this with an application class that has nothing in it but the onCreate method, it works perfectly. Upon trying this with the VolleyController application class it doesn't work. Any ideas?

**THIS WORKS**
*Empty Application Class*

```
    public class AppApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        UninstallFB.init(this, "http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

**THIS DOESN'T**

```
    public class VolleyController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG_APP = VolleyController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private static VolleyController instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //THIS DOESN'T WORK HERE???
        UninstallFB.init(this, "http://www.google.com");
        instance = this;

    }

    public static synchronized VolleyController getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return requestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (imageLoader == null) {
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.requestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.imageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG_APP : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG_APP);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (requestQueue != null) {
            requestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: But as u saying it's working in Application class then what is problem?

Comment: It works in an empty application class but not in my VolleyController application class. I'll post the difference.

Comment: What do you mean ` empty application class ` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK please see my edit

Comment: Added `VolleyController ` this `androidmanifest` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes. I added VolleyController to my manifest. All of my data loads correctly. It's only that line of code that doesn't work.